# Masking all characters of a string except for the last n characters

Tags: c#, string

I want to know how can I replace a character of a string with condition of "except last number characters"?

Example:

```
string = "4111111111111111";
```

And I want to make it that

```
new_string = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX1111"
```

In this example I replace the character to "X" except the last 4 characters.

How can I possibly achieve this?

Comment: u mean last four characters every time

Comment: @tariq, its not fixed. not everytime

Comment: so what determines how many characters you want to show

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way to think through it.  Call the last number characters to leave `n`:

1. How many characters will be replaced by `X`?  The length of the string minus `n`.
2. How can we replace characters with other characters?  You can't directly modify a `string`, but you can build a new one.
3. How to get the last `n` characters from the original string?  There's a couple ways to do this, but the simplest is probably [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx), which allows us to grab part of a string by specifying the starting point and optionally the ending point.

So it would look something like this (where `n` is the number of characters to leave from the original, and `str` is the original string - `string` can't be the name of your variable because it's a reserved keyword):

```
// 2. Start with a blank string
var new_string = "";

// 1. Replace first Length - n characters with X
for (var i = 0; i < str.Length - n; i++)
    new_string += "X";

// 3. Add in the last n characters from original string.
new_string += str.Substring(str.Length - n);
```

Comment: @cheol.lui, this may work for you, but overkill with respect to creating variables, looping and constant string + one character at a time and garbage collection...  Yes, the description works well to give you a mental "how to solve", but definitely not as efficient as other options posted.

Answer (score 31):

```
var input = "4111111111111111";
var result = new String('X', input.Length - 4) + input.Substring(input.Length - 4);

Console.WriteLine(result);

// Ouput: XXXXXXXXXXXX1111
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me and was concise. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

How about something like...

```
new_string = new String('X', YourString.Length - 4)
                  + YourString.Substring(YourString.Length - 4);
```

create a new string based on the length of the current string -4 and just have it all "X"s.  Then add on the last 4 characters of the original string

Comment: This is the most beautiful implementation of this I have ever seen. Bravo. You did what took me 7 lines in 1.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little Overkill for your ask. But here is a quick extension method that does this.

it defaults to using x as the masking Char but can be changed with an optional char

```
   public static class Masking
{
    public static string MaskAllButLast(this string input, int charsToDisplay, char maskingChar = 'x')
    {
        int charsToMask = input.Length - charsToDisplay;
        return charsToMask > 0 ? $"{new string(maskingChar, charsToMask)}{input.Substring(charsToMask)}" : input;
    }
}
```

Here a unit tests to prove it works

```
 using Xunit;

    namespace Tests
{
    public class MaskingTest
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("ThisIsATest", 4, 'x', "xxxxxxxTest")]
        [InlineData("Test", 4, null, "Test")]
        [InlineData("ThisIsATest", 4, '*', "*******Test")]
        [InlineData("Test", 16, 'x', "Test")]
        [InlineData("Test", 0, 'y', "yyyy")]
        public void Testing_Masking(string input, int charToDisplay, char maskingChar, string expected)
        {
            //Act
            string actual = input.MaskAllButLast(charToDisplay, maskingChar);

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
Char[] stringChar = string.toCharArray();
for(int x = 0; x < stringChar.length-4; x++){
    sb.append(stringChar[x]);
}
sb.append(string.substring(string.length()-4));

string = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use `Select` with index

```
string input = "4111111111111111";
string new_string = new string(input.Select((c, i) => i < input.Length - 4 ? 'X' : c).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other concise answers here did not account for strings less than n characters. Here's my take:

```
 var length = input.Length;                
 input = length > 4 ? new String('*', length - 4) + input.Substring(length - 4) : input;
```

Answer (score 1):

lui,
Please Try this one...

```
string dispString = DisplayString("4111111111111111", 4);
```

Create One function with pass original string and no of digit.

```
    public string DisplayString(string strOriginal,int lastDigit)
    {
        string strResult = new String('X', strOriginal.Length - lastDigit) + strOriginal.Substring(strOriginal.Length - lastDigit);
        return strResult;
    }
```

May be help you....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String maskedString = "...."+ (testString.substring(testString.length() - 4, testString.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I also wanted to mask all but the last 'x' characters, but only mask numbers or letters so that any - ( ), other formatting, etc would still be shown.   Here's my quick extension method that does this - hopefully it helps someone.  I started with the example from Luke Hammer, then changed the guts to fit my needs.

```
public static string MaskOnlyChars(this string input, int charsToDisplay, char maskingChar = 'x')
    {
        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();
        int intMaskCount = input.Length - charsToDisplay;

        if (intMaskCount > 0) //only mask if string is longer than requested unmasked chars
        {
            for (var intloop = 0; intloop < input.Length; intloop++)
            {
                char charCurr = Char.Parse(input.Substring(intloop, 1));
                byte[] charByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(charCurr.ToString());
                int intCurrAscii = charByte[0];

                if (intloop <= (intMaskCount - 1))
                {
                    switch (intCurrAscii)
                    {
                        case int n when (n >= 48 && n <= 57):
                            //0-9
                            sbOutput.Append(maskingChar);
                            break;

                        case int n when (n >= 65 && n <= 90):
                            //A-Z
                            sbOutput.Append(maskingChar);
                            break;

                        case int n when (n >= 97 && n <= 122):
                            //a-z
                            sbOutput.Append(maskingChar);
                            break;

                        default:
                            //Leave other characters unmasked
                            sbOutput.Append(charCurr);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Characters at end to remain unmasked
                    sbOutput.Append(charCurr);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if not enough characters to mask, show unaltered input
            return input;
        }
        return sbOutput.ToString();
    }
```